# Cmake add_compile_definitions but for all targets

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Is there a way to create definitions in cmake for all targets created. So far when I

```
add_compile_definitions(MYDEFINITION)
```

in my root CmakeLists.txt then it seems to only create those definitions for targets created in that file. But I want to create the definitions to all targets created in subdirectories. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `it seems to` soo, well... no, it does not seem to. Please create an [MCVE]. Note that `add_compile_definitions` affects targets defined _after_ it, so do `add_compile_definitions` _before_ `add_subdirectory`.

Comment: I think that was the problem yes. However the problem with doing it before the add_subdirectory is that I miss some conditionals from the subdirectory that would change those definitions. Is there a good way to deal with that in cmake?

Comment: Conditionals from subdirectory affect what is above it? A good way is not to write spaghetti code - each directory affects only what is below. Restructure the code. A good way is to never use `add_compile_definitions` and use only `target_*` stuff.

Answer (score 8):

My usual solution to set properties for all target is simply to add a `common` target, that has interface properties I want to add to all targets.

```
add_library(common INTERFACE)

target_compile_definitions(common INTERFACE MYDEFINITION)
```

The neat thing is you can also put other things like warning settings:

```
target_compile_options(common INTERFACE
    $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/Wall>
    $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU,Clang>:-Wall -Wextra>
)
```

After setting up common things in the common target, you can use it where necessary:

```
add_library(mylib ...)
add_executable(myexe ...)

target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE common)
target_link_libraries(myexe PRIVATE common)
```

Comment: Works like a champ!  Superior to sprinkling `include` everywhere, since INTERFACE is capable of propagating upwards in your project dependency chain.  Thank you for this